# Adding a Project to TFS and Ignore NuGet packages/lib Directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

My application has the following structure:

```
lib
  package1
    ...
  package2
    ...
  repositories.config
src
  MyProject.Web
    packages.config
    ...
  MyProject.sln
  NuGet.config
```

My NuGet.config file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
        <add key="repositorypath" value="../lib" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

From my understanding the disableSourceControlIntegration config option is supposed to tell visual studio to add the packages to TFS and the repository path is used to change the default location to the packages directory.

I have this setup and working fine. However when I right click on the solution file and say add to source control I can see the lib directory is ready to check-in in source control explorer. I thought this folder would be ignored and simply exists locally and then when you do a build of the project is would download the nuget packages locally.

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config should look like following. See I have solution tag instead of config.

```
 <configuration>
  <solution>
       <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
   </solution>
  </configuration>
```

Check this link out:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: Thanks I knew it must be something simple.

Comment: @AdarshShah, does this work for you from any NuGet.config file, or only from under .nuget subdirectory next to solution file?
See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24406583/107604.