# Visual Studio local workspace + Enable Nuget Package Restore (disableSourceControlIntegration)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I was happy with disableSourceControlIntegration = true (and /packages/ not checked-in to TFS) in server workspace.

Now I decided to try local workspace and boom - it finds thousands of 'Detected Changes' in /packages/, which should be ignored because of disableSourceControlIntegration = true in my NuGet.Config

Anyone got local workspace and package restore working together? 
I believe that adding .tfignore is a really bad option.
Btw, I'm using VS13.

Comment: Why is using a `.tfignore` "a really bad option"> 1. It works, 2. consider `.gitignore` etc.: this is the typical approach to gettng a VCS to not include files.

Comment: @Richard - apparently 1. it doesn't work, 2. doesn't tell VS itself to ignore these in vc.. see https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4072

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That bug report does not reflect my experience. Remember you also need to enable NuGet package restore (otherwise ignoring the packages folder makes no sence). VS doesn't add files to non-project folders automatically.

Comment: @Richard - automatic nuget package restore is enabled by default in VS 2012 or greater.  Disabling the source control integration is not.

Answer (score 5):

In your solution directory root, create a folder called `.nuget` and add a `nuget.config` with the following contents.

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

Additional configuration settings can be found here: https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings

You might also need to close/reopen Visual Studio and have to revert pending changes in TFS Source Control for your `\packages` folder (if you have pending additions).

Comment: It seems (at least with NuGet 2.7-2.8) that the mentioned section works _only_ from .nuget/NuGet.config. The docs explicitly say that the section should be put there, but do not mention that it would not be honored if placed anywhere higher in folder hierarchy.

Comment: Sergii's got it. If you want to disable source control you MUST put the nuget.config in a solution level .nuget folder. All the other settings seem to work from any folder above solution level, but not that one.

Comment: This was driving me crazy because adding the setting as specified appeared to have no effect. Restarting VS as suggested above allowed the setting to work correctly.